# how to create multiple foreach with one save?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, yii, multiple-columns

I create multiple foreach in the controller function framework yii and create one storage, but the data stored only the last foreach data, how the solution  master?

```
$arrItems = array();
$data = LineTransaksi::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('id_header'=>$id));
foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_bgs'] as $q3k => $q3v)
{
    if(isset($data[$q3k]))
    {
        $tabdata=LineTransaksi::model()->findByPk($data[$q3k]->id_line);  
    }
    else
    {
        $tabdata=new LineTransaksi;
    }
    $tabdata->jml_kembali_bgs=$q3v;
    $arrItems[] = $tabdata;
}
foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_retak'] as $q3r => $q3t)
{
    if(isset($data[$q3r]))
    {
        $tabdata=LineTransaksi::model()->findByPk($data[$q3r]->id_line);  
    }
    else
    {
        $tabdata=new LineTransaksi;
    }
    $tabdata->jml_kembali_retak=$q3t;
    $tabdata->last_updated_date=new CDbExpression('now()');
    $arrItems[] = $tabdata;
}
foreach ($arrItems as $object)
{
    $object->save();
}
```

thanks for the attention.

Comment: Why not do `$tabdata->save()` and not have the last `foreach`?

Comment: use $arrItems.push($tabdata);

Comment: because if "$ tabdata-> save ();" twice, the function aftersave repeats twice. @MilanChheda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you use `$arrItems[] = $tabdata;` you are replacing the $arrItems[] array with the new values in $tabdata.

You should use `array_push($arrItems, $tabdata);` instead.

So that your code should look like:

```
$arrItems = array();
foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_bgs'] as $q3k => $q3v)
{
if(isset($data[$q3k]))
{
    $tabdata=LineTransaksi::model()->findByPk($data[$q3k]->id_line);  
}
else
{
    $tabdata=new LineTransaksi;
}
$tabdata->jml_kembali_bgs=$q3v;
array_push($arrItems, $tabdata);
}
foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_retak'] as $q3r => $q3t)
{
if(isset($data[$q3r]))
{
    $tabdata=LineTransaksi::model()->findByPk($data[$q3r]->id_line);  
}
else
{
    $tabdata=new LineTransaksi;
}
$tabdata->jml_kembali_retak=$q3t;
$tabdata->last_updated_date=new CDbExpression('now()');
array_push($arrItems, $tabdata);
}
foreach ($arrItems as $object)
{
$object->save();
}
```

**UPDATED:**

You could try this:

```
$arrItems = array();
foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_bgs'] as $q3k => $q3v)
{
if(isset($data[$q3k]))
{
    $tabdata=LineTransaksi::model()->findByPk($data[$q3k]->id_line);  
}
else
{
    $tabdata=new LineTransaksi;
}
$tabdata->jml_kembali_bgs=$q3v;
array_push($arrItems, $tabdata);
}
foreach ($arrItems as $object)
{
$object->save();
}
foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_retak'] as $q3r => $q3t)
{
if(isset($data[$q3r]))
{
    $tabdata=LineTransaksi::model()->findByPk($data[$q3r]->id_line);  
}
else
{
    $tabdata=new LineTransaksi;
}
$tabdata->jml_kembali_retak=$q3t;
$tabdata->last_updated_date=new CDbExpression('now()');
array_push($arrItems, $tabdata);
}
foreach ($arrItems as $object)
{
$object->save();
}
```

Comment: Just check what is in $arrItems using `print_r($arrItems)` before the last `foreach ($arrItems as $object)` loop.

Comment: if I check `print_r ($arrItems)` the data is filled, but it does not want to be stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks Anjana. But still the same, the first foreach "jml_kembali_bgs" can not save to the database

Comment: @SatryaCahya, what if you tried to add another `foreach ($arrItems as $object)
{
$object->save();
}` after the first `foreach ($_POST['jml_kembali_bgs'] as $q3k => $q3v)` loop.

Comment: successful, but the sum of data in my `function aftersave` repeats twice. @Anjana

Comment: @SatryaCahya, I updated the code. 
Maybe, you better re initialize the `$arrItems = array();` after that first data set is being saved.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved, I added a condition in the aftershave function.